# python error: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a problem with my current code, I'm trying to count on each 69 rows to see how many row of channels I have got in a sqlite3 database.

When I try this:

```
cur.execute('SELECT channel FROM programs WHERE channel GROUP BY channel')
row_count = len(cur.fetchall)
print row_count
```

It give me the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

The error are jumping on this line:

```
row_count = len(cur.fetchall)
```

Can you please help me how I can count on each 69 rows to see how many row of channels I have got in a sqlite3 database?

Comment: your sql doesn't look right ... the Where clause should have a condition ... or you should leave it out. You might want `SELECT channel FROM programs GROUP BY channel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to get the length of te `cur.fetchall` *method object*. You didn't call the method.

You'd add `()` after the method name to call it and get the full results first:

```
row_count = len(cur.fetchall())
```

However, this is hardly efficient. Ask the database to get your row count instead:

```
cur.execute('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT channel) FROM programs WHERE channel')
row_count, = cur.fetchone()
```

where I assume you meant `WHERE channel` to be treated as a [boolean expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#booleanexpr); a cast to NUMERIC and any rows that are non-zero are included in the count.